# How to format a json.dump() file without a unique key?

Tags: json, django, parsing

I'm trying to dump a django database into a json file. The json file needs to be in the following format for my html table implementation to work:

```
[{"title": "hello world", "author": "John Doe","price": 0}]
```

when I call `json.dump()` I receive a dictionary of an auto generated keys with another dictionary as its values, like so:

```
{"1": {"price": 20, "title": "78BBOT", "author": "AT5L89"}}
```

Here is my current django/python code to generate the dump:

```
data = Book.objects.values('title', 'author', 'price')
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
     json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Is there a way I can parse this information in the format of the first example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ignore the keys in your JSON dump:

```
json.dump(data.values(), outfile)
```